# Overcoming Meteor/Typescript/Angular compiler missing errors

Tags: typescript, meteor, compiler-errors, angular-meteor

I have come across several types of errors I can write in Meteor/Angular code that seem to break the compiler without throwing an error.  Some examples:

```
export const foo = {
  propA: 'abc',
  propB: 123;
  propc: 'value'
}
```

where the semicolon erroneously in the middle of the object breaks things badly.
Another:

```
private _functionName( param1: string, param2: boolean; param3: string ): void { // do stuff here  }
```

Where again the semicolon is erroneously placed.  Third:

```
const propertyName = thisArray.map( thing => return thing._id );
```

where the callback function should be wrapped in braces (a semicolon might've helped there too).  Fourth:

```
import style    from './this.component.scss';
```

where the specified .scss file does not exist ( if it exists but is 0-byte that will pass - it's only the case that it doesn't exist that fails).

Each of these mistakes results in a clean compile on the server side, and an error-free client console with an application that hangs on the loading screen.

There is a question of if/how to reproduce; below are the specific environmental parameters I'm working under, on Amazon Linux.

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "3.4.34",
    "@types/meteor": "^1.3.31",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.34",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "chai-spies": "0.7.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.3",
    "@mahpah/angular-cropper": "0.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/htmlparser2": "^3.7.29",
    "angular-draggable-droppable": "^1.0.1",
    "angular2-meteor": "^0.7.1",
    "angular2-meteor-accounts-ui": "^1.0.0",
    "angular2-meteor-polyfills": "^0.1.1",
    "angular2-meteor-tests-polyfills": "0.0.2",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "htmlparser2": "^3.9.2",
    "meteor-node-stubs": "^0.2.11",
    "meteor-rxjs": "^0.4.7",
    "ng-gallery": "^0.7.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "^3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "simpl-schema": "^0.2.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.11"
  }

    meteor-base@1.1.0             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
    mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
    mongo@1.2.0                   # The database Meteor supports right now
    reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
    tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

    standard-minifier-css@1.3.4   # CSS minifier run for production mode
    standard-minifier-js@2.1.1    # JS minifier run for production mode
    es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.

    angular2-compilers
    practicalmeteor:mocha
    xolvio:cleaner
    hwillson:stub-collections
    dispatch:mocha-phantomjs
    shell-server@0.2.4
    aldeed:collection2-core
    aldeed:schema-deny
    aldeed:schema-index
    mdg:validated-method
    mdg:validation-error
    accounts-password@1.4.0
    alanning:roles
    tmeasday:publish-counts
    dburles:collection-helpers
    matb33:collection-hooks
    email@1.2.3
    edgee:slingshot
    dynamic-import@0.1.1
    http@1.2.12

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
  }
}
```

My question, then, is this:

Is there a linter, or some debugger log that I am not seeing that would aid in troubleshooting?  I recognize that some IDE's would highlight these errors (especially the missing SCSS file) but that doesn't answer my question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your problem is, but in all cases you mentioned with default compiler settings I get errors. The following snippet:

```
import style    from './bla'; // with bla.js being an empty file

export const foo = {
  propA: 'abc',
  propB: 123;
  propc: 'value'
}

function _functionName( param1: string, param2: boolean; param3: string ): void {}
```

Produces the following output:

```
test.ts(5,13): error TS1005: ',' expected.
test.ts(10,56): error TS1005: ',' expected.
```

While the empty module does not produce a compiler error it does warn you about this in VS Code.

If you want a linter for Typescript, tslint is a great tool. But your first two are definitely compiler errors (at least with TS 2.5)

Comment: Let's focus on these one at a time and see if they're environmental or if it's in a specific place.  For example, the last one: the specific place where this fails on mine is assigning a private method to an Angular service.  I can reproduce this at will.  I'll edit my response to include version information and see if I can put a small project together that reproduces.